# Why won't the known color show in a propertygrid control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on Custom Settings for my application.  I have created a class that holds all of the settings as public properties to be displayed in a property grid.  The set/get write to and read from a database using custom functions.  This all works great for my needs.  I am having troubles displaying colors the way I think they should be displayed in the property grid.  The property grid only uses the RGB value even for known colors.

Is there a way to have the property grid display the known color instead of the RGB value?

Here is my property from my settings class.

```
    <CategoryAttribute("Signature Capture"), _
    DescriptionAttribute("Sets the Pen color"), _
    DisplayName("PenColor"), _
    BrowsableAttribute(True), _
    ReadOnlyAttribute(False), _
    DefaultValueAttribute(GetType(Color), "Black"), _
    RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)> _
    Public Property SignatureCapturePenColor() As Color
        Get
            Dim myset As New mySettings
            Return Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(myset.GetSetting("SignatureCapturePenColor", mySettings.e_Scope.Tech)))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            Dim myset As New mySettings
            myset.SetSetting("SignatureCapturePenColor", value.ToArgb, mySettings.e_Scope.Tech)
            Dim ncSet As New ncSettings
            ncSet.NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property
```

This is an example of what the property grid looks like:

[image: Property Grid]

This should be displayed as "Black" instead of "0,0,0".

Is this even possible?

I can post more code or explain more if needed.  This is my first question, so please go easy on me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the ARGB value to store and return the color so it "thinks" you are trying to define a custom color.

Use and save the color name instead..

```
 Public Property SignatureCapturePenColor() As Color
    Get
        Dim myset As New mySettings
        Return Color.FromName(myset.GetSetting("SignatureCapturePenColorName", mySettings.e_Scope.Tech))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Color)
        Dim myset As New mySettings
        myset.SetSetting("SignatureCapturePenColorName", value.Name, mySettings.e_Scope.Tech)
        Dim ncSet As New ncSettings
        ncSet.NotifyPropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response!  I tried this same technique several times and could not get it to work correct.  My problem was with the Setter not setting value.name.

Comment: Not sure about your settings collection so can't say. All I can tell you is the property grid works as expected when you just save and retrieve the name to / from a variable.